# Real analysis based on rings and ideals

Tags: real-analysis, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be the ring of all the real valued continuous functions on the closed unit interval. Show that $ M=\{ f\in R:f(1/3)=0 \} $ is a maximal ideal

Comment: The usual characterizations of maximal ideals apply; one in particular makes for a short proof. I'm assuming you already understand how to show it's an ideal....

Comment: Yeah, I understood how to prove it is an ideal. I just want to figure out how to prove it is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

Think about $R/M$. The cosets of $M$ are just the subcollections of functions that have the same output for the input $1/3$. This output could be any real number, so there is an obvious map suggested:

$\theta:C([0,1])\to \Bbb R$

$\theta(f):=f(1/3)$

Show that this is a ring homomorphism of $C([0,1])$ onto $\Bbb R$, with kernel $M$. Conclude by the first isomorphism theorem that $M$ is a ideal maximal.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is $M$? What kinds of functions are in $M$? Consider the series of functions
$$
f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R, n\in\mathbb N
$$
where $f(1/3)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ almost everywhere else, except for a continuous interpolation in a neighbourhood of radius $1/n$ around $1/3$. Then all these functions $f$ are in $M$, and they act as a 'bump function' as $n\to\infty$. If you take any continuous function $g$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then $f_ng$ (for a sufficiently large $n$) $g$ will have $f_ng(1/3)=0$ and $\|f_ng-g\|<\varepsilon$ for the $L^1$ or $L^2$ norm. In this way, you can approach what elements are in $M$, and so try to prove it is maximal.